# How to get the command behind std::process::Command in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm passing around instances of [`std::process::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html). Before executing a command I'd like to log the entire command. For instance, if I'm given a `command` instance that has been constructed like that:

```rust
let command = Command::new("sh")
    .arg("-c")
    .arg("echo hello")
```

I would like to write a log message like:

```
Executing command: 'sh' '-c' 'echo hello'
```

The API looks quite limited though. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Debug` is implemented for `Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#impl-Debug).

```rust
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let mut command = Command::new("ls");
    command.arg("-l");
    println!("{:?}", command);
}
```

Output: `"ls" "-l"`

Comment: But there is no way of accessing the command parts manually to have control over formatting?

Comment: I'd simplified the problem for the question, in my use case I wanted to programmatically access the command fragments. This doesn't seem possible. I'll accept the answer, but man, what an unfortunate omission in the API.

Answer (score 0):

You would like to get access to private fields in the `command` struct.  Private fields are not accessible by design.

However, when a Debug trait has been implemented for the struct, the private members are 'printed' using the `{:?}` format option.

To access those private members programmatically, use the `format!()` macro.  This returns a `std::String` and accepts the `{:?}` formatting option.  This only works because the Debug trait has been implemented for Command.

```
fn main() {
    let mut command = Command::new("ls");
    command.arg("-l");
    let command_string: String = std::format!("{:?}", command);

    // Print the command_string to standard output 
    println!("cmd: {}", command_string);

    // split the command string accordinig to whitespace
    let command_parts = command_string.split(' ');

    // print the individual parts of the command_string
    for (index, part) in command_parts.enumerate() {
        println!("part[{}]: {}", index, part);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$> test_prog
   cmd: "ls" "-l"
   part[0]: "ls"
   part[1]: "-l"
$>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in general, `split(' ')` can split on spaces in arguments. You'd need to properly re-parse the string, accounting for quoting -- quite ugly.